# jQuery - how to perform 'each' function on selected elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I want to disable all the buttons on the screen.

I've tried this:

```
$(":button").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

It's not working, I think I'm not using the word "this" the right way.

Edit: the buttons are in table cells

I've tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
$("#gameboard-table tbody tr td button").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: `$(":button").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: check my answer and use my jsfiddle link to reproduce the problem

Comment: also can you check your console or firebug debugger to tell what error does it throws ?

Comment: Are you including jQuery ?

Comment: does that code working for dynamic div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `<button>` tags

```
$("button").attr("disabled", true);
```

for `<input type="button">` tags

```
$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", true);
```

**FOR JQuery 1.6+ change `attr` to `prop`**

or simply write the disabling line in plain javascript

```
$("button, input[type=button]").each(function () {
    this.disabled=true;
});
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to disable buttons which are created dynamically, make sure you run the code after the buttons are created, and not before/on page load.

if you are using Ajax, you will need to disable the buttons on the ajax success function, after you update the table with the buttons.

**Below is an example of what you need to do:**

```
var options = {
    type: "POST",
    //...
    //more ajax vars 
    //...
    success: function (response) {

        //...
        //update your table with the buttons,
        //...

        //disable buttons using one of the methods from above:
        $("button, input[type=button]").each(function () {
            this.disabled=true;
        });
    }
};
$.ajax(options);
```

Comment: if the dynamic elements are created inside the ajax's success function, then yes, it will work. as long as the code is being run *after* the creation of the dynamic elements, it will work

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `each()`. Simply can use

```
$(":button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

or

```
$(":button").attr("disabled", true);
```

```html
<button>x</button>
<button>y</button>
<button>x</button>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(":button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    //$("button").attr("disabled", true);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working on buttons that are not inside a container. I forgot to mention the buttons are in a table. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
//for <button> tags --> pls uncomment below line 
      $(":button").attr("disabled", "disabled");



    //Even your code works !!!! ---> uncomment below lines to see

    $(":button").each(function () {
       //$(this).attr("disabled", true);
    });
```

as far as I checked it is working even inside table,

[Here is my jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/9tzhabzw/16/) : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/9tzhabzw/16/

EDITED :

please try below fiddle and code

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/9tzhabzw/32/) : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/9tzhabzw/32/

```
//for <button> tags --> pls uncomment below line 
 // $(":button").attr("disabled", "disabled");


$(":button").click(function(){
//alert(this.id);
})

$(".btn1").click(function(){
$("#mytable").append("<tr><td>"+'<button class = "btn" >new button</buttton>'+"</td></tr>");
})

//Even your code works !!!! ---> uncomment below lines to see


jQuery('body').on("click", "#click5", function() {
      $(".btn").each(function () {
       $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    });
})

jQuery('body').on("click", "#click6", function() {
      $(".btn").each(function () {
       $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    });
})
```

Here is why dynamic generated div click does not work :

[In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

[Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: let me know if my jsfiddle link helps you to understand your problem

Comment: Thank you. It's working, but not on my table. My table is created dynamically but I run this code only after it created. Can the fact that the table created dynamically be the problem?

Comment: hmmm ok let me try it dynamically than

Comment: I've tried it, it's working only when I started to use the page, but not on the $(document).ready function, have any idea why? this function is executed only after the table is loaded.

Comment: it depends on how you load the buttons. do you load them using Ajax? what do you mean by "dynamically" ?

Comment: Yes I'm using Ajax to get info I put on the buttons and then create the table.

Comment: then it will never work on document ready. you need to disable the buttons on the Ajax success function. i will update my answer with an example